# How to call list like values from the variable file in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have a ansible playbook where i have multiple parameters to be passed which are sometimes lengthy enough and makes play look fatty hence i'm thinking about creating a variable file and keeping all the possible values in that file so as to call them from there to make play slim and at the same time this will avoid making changes to the playbook and we can make adjustment to the variable file like `cloud_vars.yml`.

### Below is my variable file:

```
$ cat azure_vars.yml
---
azure_subnet_name: "infra"
azure_os_disk_type: Standard_LRS
azure_nprod_vnet: "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg001/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet"
azure_prod03_vnet: "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg002/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet"
azure_prod02_vnet: "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg003/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet"
public_key: "ssh-rsa:XXXX "
azure_image_id: "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/mgt01-rg001/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/imagegallery/images/myimage/versions/0.0.3"
    
# Azure domains
azure_domains:
  - "eu-azrc1"
  - "us-azrc2"
  - "us-sea01"

# Resource group
azure_res_group:
  - "rg001"
  - "rg002"
  - "rg003"

# Azure locations
azure_location:
  - "westus2"
  - "westeurope"
  - "southcentralus"
...
```

### Playbook Below

Below is the play which is setting `facts` for later use in the playbook, i am looking forward to know as how to use `azure_domains` `azure_res_group` and  `azure_location` variable from the vaiable file as they are defined in a list there, as of now i have hard-coded the names and location etc.

```
$ cat new_vm_Creation.yml
---
- name: create azure vm
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
   -  include_vars: azure_vars.yml

   - set_fact:
      host: "{{ azure_vm_name.split('.') }}"

   - set_fact:
       azure_domain: "{{ host.1 }}.{{ host.2 }}"

   - name: azure_domain
     debug:
      msg: "{{ azure_domain }}"

   - set_fact:
      azure_location: "westus2"
     when: azure_domain == "us-sea01"

   - set_fact:
      azure_location: "westeurope"
     when: azure_domain == "eu-azrc1"

   - set_fact:
      azure_location: "southcentralus"
     when: azure_domain == "us-azrc2"

   - name: azure_location
     debug:
      msg: "{{ azure_location }}"

   - set_fact:
      res_group: "rg001"
     when: azure_domain == "us-sea01"

   - set_fact:
      res_group: "rg002"
     when: azure_domain == "eu-azrc1"

   - set_fact:
      res_group: "rg003"
     when: azure_domain == "us-azrc2"

   - name: Resource Group
     debug:
      msg: "{{ res_group }}"

   - set_fact:
      vnet: "{{ azure_nprod_vnet }}"
     when: azure_domain == "us-sea01"

   - set_fact:
      vnet: "{{ azure_prod03_vnet }}"
     when: azure_domain == "eu-azrc1"

   - set_fact:
      vnet: "{{ azure_prod02_vnet }}"
     when: azure_domain == "us-azrc2"

   - name: Vnet
     debug:
      msg: "{{ vnet }}"

   - name: create network security group that allows ssh
     azure_rm_securitygroup:
      resource_group: "{{ res_group }}"
      location: "{{ location }}"
      name: "{{ azure_vm_name }}-nsg"
      rules:
        - name: ssh
          protocol: Tcp
          destination_port_range: 22
          access: Allow
          priority: 100
          direction: Inbound

       - name: create virtual network interface card
         azure_rm_networkinterface:
          resource_group: "{{ res_group }}"
          location: "{{ location }}"
          name: "{{ azure_vm_name }}-nic1"
          subnet: "{{ azure_subnet_name }}"
          virtual_network: "{{ vnet }}"
          security_group: "{{ azure_vm_name }}-nsg"
          enable_accelerated_networking: true
          public_ip: no
          state: present
    
       - name: create vm
         azure_rm_virtualmachine:
          resource_group: "{{ res_group }}"
          location: "{{ location }}"
          name: "{{ azure_vm_name }}"
          vm_size: Standard_D4s_v3
          admin_username: some_id
          ssh_password_enabled: false
          ssh_public_keys:
            - path: /home/some_id/.ssh/authorized_keys
              key_data: "{{ public_key }}"
          network_interfaces: "{{ azure_vm_name }}-nic1"
          os_disk_name: "{{ azure_vm_name }}-osdisk"
          managed_disk_type: "{{ azure_os_disk_type }}"
          os_disk_caching: ReadWrite
          os_type: Linux
          image:
            id: "{{ azure_image_id }}"
            publisher: redhat
          plan:
            name: rhel-lvm78
            product: rhel-byos
            publisher: redhat
    ...
```

Comment: For the record, this have been cross questionnes here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64106956/2123530

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define those structures in your `azure_vars.yml` file, including the jinja2 templates, but just with the knowledge that putting them in the vars file **does not resolve them** -- jinja2 template evaluation is recursive in ansible, so the first time they are *used* in when you will see either success or the dreaded `"VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"`

Given `azure_vars.yml` of

```yaml
azure_nprod_vnet: "/subscriptions/alpha-nprod/resourceGroups/rg001/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet"
azure_prod03_vnet: "/subscriptions/beta-prod03/resourceGroups/rg002/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet"
azure_prod02_vnet: "/subscriptions/charlie-prod02/resourceGroups/rg003/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet"

things_by_azure_domain:
  "us-sea01":
    azure_location: "westus2"
    res_group: "rg001"
    vnet: "{{ azure_nprod_vnet }}"
  "eu-azrc1": 
    azure_location: "westeurope"
    res_group: "rg002"
    vnet: "{{ azure_prod03_vnet }}"
  "us-azrc2": 
    azure_location: "southcentralus"
    res_group: "rg003"
    vnet: "{{ azure_prod02_vnet }}"

vnet: "{{ things_by_azure_domain[azure_domain].vnet }}"
```

then after putting your `azure_domain` into scope, use of `{{ vnet }}` will recursively evaluate that expression:

```yaml
  tasks:
  # OBSERVE that we can include this, even with `azure_domain` not yet defined
  # because `include_vars` DOES NOT evaluate those jinja2 expressions
  - include_vars: azure_vars.yml
  - set_fact:
      azure_domain: us-azrc2
  - debug:
      var: vnet
```

yielding

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vnet": "/subscriptions/charlie-prod02/resourceGroups/rg003/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet"
```

But, as I said, you will need to exercise caution because a fat-finger will not end well:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - include_vars: azure_vars.yml
  - set_fact:
      azure_domain: us-yankee-doodle
  - debug:
      var: vnet
```

yields

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vnet": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

But at least with my ansible 2.9.13, running at higher verbosity does surface the root cause:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vnet": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'dict object' has no attribute 'us-yankee-doodle'"
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for detail explanation, it helps a lot. However, i would like to know can i dapt that into my `playbook` I updated a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea from `@mdaniel` but I don't know who to get them into your `playbook` later for different `tasks`:

Based on your post, you can little align your `azure_vars.yml`  in order to get them all in the same sequence which will help to call them easily in the play later.

So, I have aligned US region first following Europe in the last.

### Var files:

```
# Azure domains
azure_domains:
  - us-sea01
  - us-azrc2
  - eu-azrc1


# Resource group
azure_res_group:
  - rg001
  - rg002
  - rg003

# Azure locations
azure_location:
  - westus2
  - southcentralus
  - westeurope
...
```

### Play:

Now slightly you can make your `Playbook` slimmer which will help you modify only `azure_vars.yml` rather in the play.

```
---
- name: create azure vm
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
   -  include_vars: azure_vars.yml

   - set_fact:
      host: "{{ azure_vm_name.split('.') }}"

   - set_fact:
       domain: "{{ host.1 }}.{{ host.2 }}"

   - name: Domain
     debug:
      msg: "{{ domain }}"

   - set_fact:
      location: "{{ azure_location[0] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[0]'

   - set_fact:
      location: "{{ azure_location[1] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[1]'

   - set_fact:
      location: "{{ azure_location[2] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[2]'

   - name: Location
     debug:
      msg: "{{ location }}"

   - set_fact:
      res_group: "{{ azure_res_group[0] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[0]'

   - set_fact:
      res_group: "{{ azure_res_group[1] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[1]'

   - set_fact:
      res_group: "{{ azure_res_group[2] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[2]'

   - name: Resource Group
     debug:
      msg: "{{ res_group }}"

   - set_fact:
      vnet: "{{ azure_nprod_vnet }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[0]'

   - set_fact:
      vnet: "{{ azure_prod03_vnet }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[2]'

   - set_fact:
      vnet: "{{ azure_prod02_vnet }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[1]'

   - name: Vnet
     debug:
      msg: "{{ vnet }}"
```