# How to Club multiple ansible condition into one based on the set_facts

Tags: azure, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

While going through one of the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068225/how-to-call-list-like-values-from-the-variable-file-in-ansible) for Ansible, was interested an usage of `set_fact` with different conditional checks.
However, I answered on the post based on my approach, but, I still see there can be an improvement to club multiple conditions for similar task like determine the `location` `resource group` and `vnet`.

Below is the `playbook` and variables file  `azure_vars.yml`

Playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: create azure vm
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
   -  include_vars: azure_vars.yml

   - set_fact:
      host: "{{ azure_vm_name.split('.') }}"

   - set_fact:
       domain: "{{ host.1 }}.{{ host.2 }}"

   - name: Domain
     debug:
      msg: "{{ domain }}"

   - set_fact:
      location: "{{ azure_location[0] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[0]'

   - set_fact:
      location: "{{ azure_location[1] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[1]'

   - set_fact:
      location: "{{ azure_location[2] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[2]'

   - name: Location
     debug:
      msg: "{{ location }}"

   - set_fact:
      res_group: "{{ azure_res_group[0] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[0]'

   - set_fact:
      res_group: "{{ azure_res_group[1] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[1]'

   - set_fact:
      res_group: "{{ azure_res_group[2] }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[2]'

   - name: Resource Group
     debug:
      msg: "{{ res_group }}"

   - set_fact:
      vnet: "{{ azure_nprod_vnet }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[0]'

   - set_fact:
      vnet: "{{ azure_prod03_vnet }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[2]'

   - set_fact:
      vnet: "{{ azure_prod02_vnet }}"
     when: 'domain == azure_domain[1]'

   - name: Vnet
     debug:
      msg: "{{ vnet }}"
```

Variable files: this file contains all the variable which will be a part of `playbook` and imported as `include_vars` under task section.

*azure_vars.yml*

```yaml
---
azure_nprod_vnet: "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg001/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet"
azure_prod02_vnet: "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg003/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet"
azure_prod03_vnet: "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg002/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet"

    
# Azure domain
azure_domains:
  - us-sea01
  - us-azrc2
  - eu-azrc1


# Resource group
azure_res_group:
  - rg001
  - rg002
  - rg003

# Azure locations
azure_location:
  - westus2
  - southcentralus
  - westeurope
```

Expected would be to club below three into one condition:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    location: "{{ azure_location[0] }}"
  when: 'domain == azure_domain[0]'

- set_fact:
    location: "{{ azure_location[1] }}"
  when: 'domain == azure_domain[1]'

- set_fact:
    location: "{{ azure_location[2] }}"
  when: 'domain == azure_domain[2]'
```

May be something like:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    location:
      - azure_location[0]
      - azure_location[1]
      - azure_location[2]
  when:
    - 'domain == azure_domain[0]
    - 'domain == azure_domain[1]
    - 'domain == azure_domain[2]
```

Comment: Silly question, for you but should be for the OP of the other question. How to you end up with `zone-srv`  building it via `"{{ host.1 }}.{{ host.2 }}"`? Mind the usage of the dot there. I could understand it with `"{{ host.1 }}-{{ host.2 }}"`, though.

Comment: Also, you defined `azure_domains` in the included vars, but you use `azure_domain`, I guess this is a typo?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, the domain name `"{{ host.1 }}.{{ host.2 }}"` as they have names like for example `myhost01.nxdi.us-sea01.example.com` as checked with OP.

and indeed in in the `include_vars` its `azure_domains`.

Comment: Still: `"myhost01.nxdi.us-sea01.example.com".split('.')` -> `[myhost01, nxdi, us-sea01, example, com]` -> `"{{ host.1 }}.{{ host.2 }}"` -> `nxdi.us-sea01`, which you won't find in `azure_domains`. You can find it if you assign `host.2` to `domain`, indeed, but not if you assign `"{{ host.1 }}.{{ host.2 }}"` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using a [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) and [`zip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest) filter, or in the older fashion way, with a [`with_together`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-together) — not recommended anymore, if you want to future-proof your playbooks.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    azure_vm_name: foo.bar.us-sea01.whatever.example.org

  tasks:
    - include_vars: azure_vars.yml

    - set_fact:
        host: "{{ azure_vm_name.split('.') }}"

    - set_fact:
        domain: "{{ host.2 }}"

    - name: Domain
      debug:
        msg: "{{ domain }}"

    - set_fact:
        location: "{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ azure_domains | zip(azure_location) | list }}"
      when: 'domain == item.0'

    - name: Location
      debug:
       msg: "{{ location }}"
```

And the variable file *azure_vars.yml*:

```yaml
azure_domains:
  - us-sea01
  - us-azrc2
  - eu-azrc1

azure_location:
  - westus2
  - southcentralus
  - westeurope
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [include_vars] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Domain] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "us-sea01"
}

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['us-sea01', 'westus2'])
skipping: [localhost] => (item=['us-azrc2', 'southcentralus']) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=['eu-azrc1', 'westeurope']) 

TASK [Location] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "westus2"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

This said there is another possibility, using Python's capacities of Ansible. You could use the [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.index) method of a list to target the element of `azure_location` being at the same position as `domain` in `azure_domains`.
e.g. if the `domain` is at position `2` of `azure_domains`, you'll get the element of position `2` in `azure_location`.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    azure_vm_name: foo.bar.us-sea01.whatever.example.org

  tasks:
    - include_vars: azure_vars.yml

    - set_fact:
        host: "{{ azure_vm_name.split('.') }}"

    - set_fact:
        domain: "{{ host.2 }}"

    - name: Domain
      debug:
        msg: "{{ domain }}"

    - set_fact:
        location: "{{ azure_location[azure_domains.index(domain)] }}"

    - name: Location
      debug:
       msg: "{{ location }}"
```

And the same variable file *azure_vars.yml*, this yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] ******************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [include_vars] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Domain] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "us-sea01"
}

TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Location] *************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "westus2"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Which is not using a loop, so makes an easier recap.